# Producing key:value pairs from existing pairs in nested dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, key-value-coding

I have a rather algorithmic question. I’m using Python so that would be a bonus but in essence it’s about how to approach a problem.

I have a nested dictionary where for each customer, there are their relations with another customers. Basically if they enjoy same things, they are more compatible. The way this is calculated is that, for first customer the compatibility is calculated with every other customers, but for the second customer’s loop first one is skipped because it had been calculated already. You end up a dictionary something like this

```
Custdict={‘1’:{‘2’:1,’3’:0,’4’:3},’2’:{‘3’:1,’4’:2}…}
```

So for the last customer let’s say 10th, there is no entry for it as a key/value pair since it’s calculated in previous ones. My question is, how can I obtain this data from previous ones and add them as key/values in later ones. So above dictionary should become

```
Custdict={‘1’:{‘2’:1,’3’:0,’4’:3},’2’:{‘1’:1,‘3’:1,’4’:2}…}
```

I did something online search to see if there is such algorithm but couldn’t find anything

Comment: You should fix your quotation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple solution, you can just iterate over all values in the dictionary, and for each customer-customer pair `(i, j)`, you also set the value for `(j, i)`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
cust = {
    1: {
        2: 1,
        3: 0
    },
    2: {
        3: 1
    }
}
new_cust = defaultdict(dict)
for customer in cust.keys():
    for neighbour in cust[customer].keys():
        new_cust[neighbour][customer] = cust[customer][neighbour]
        new_cust[customer][neighbour] = cust[customer][neighbour]
print(dict(new_cust))
# prints {2: {1: 1, 3: 1}, 1: {2: 1, 3: 0}, 3: {1: 0, 2: 1}}
```

Comment: Thank you that solves it. I always thought about modifying the existing dictionary, creating a new one from that one was way easier it seems. In that case, a similar solution is  for key1,val1 in cust.items():
    for key2 in val1:
        new_cust[key2][key1]=cust[key1][key2]
        new_cust[key1][key2]=cust[key1][key2]
        
print(new_cust)